# No provider for className exception

Tags: angular

This is the structure of my project: http://image.prntscr.com/image/67f292ebbd804ed9b1e2e2c8d4fe471e.png

In boot-client.ts I have:

```
import { MockConnection, MockBackend  } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { AuthGuard } from './components/_guards/auth.guard';

bootstrap(App, [
  routing,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  FormBuilder,
  AuthGuard,
  AuthenticationService,
  fakeBackendProvider,
  MockBackend,
  BaseRequestOptions
]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

And in the terminal I get errors that there is no provider for AuthGuard and for MockBackend. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That is the original exception message: "No provider for AuthGuard" and "No provider for MockBackend"

Comment: Sounds weird. I guess you need to provide more details. For example a Plunker. You get an up-to-date Angular2 template from the "life example" link at the top of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You can download my project here without the node modules here: http://www.filedropper.com/steve-original

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to download, but I probably would have a look in a simple Plunker that allows to reproduce.